# how to fix an "uncaught reference error"?

Tags: javascript, html, function, undefined

I have defined the function calculateChange() in the head yet I get an error saying it is undefined at the onclick in the button input, what do I do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            initalP=parseFloat(document.getElementById('pennies').value);
                quarters=Math.floor(initalP/25);
                dimes=Math.floor((initalP%25)/10);
                nickels=Math.floor(((initalP/25)%10)/5);
                pennies=(initalP - quarters - dimes - nickels);
                total=(quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies); 
            function calculateChange()
            {


                document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML=
                <ul>
                    <li>'The total number of coins is ' + total + '.'</li>
                    <li> + quarters + ' Qaurters' +</li>
                    <li> + dimes + ' Dimes' +</li>
                    <li> + nickels + ' Nickels' +</li>
                    <li> + pennies + ' Pennies' +</li>


                </ul>;

            }
        </script>

<input type="button" value="click me for change" onclick="calculateChange();">

<div id="outPut"></div>
```

I expect the shown math equations answers to be shown in the output div but when I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: Could you show the button where you call the function `calculateChange()`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML= <ul>(...etc)` is invalid syntax... the syntax is wrong, so the function doesn't get defined

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass string values to innerHTML atribute. By fixing it, your function should run.

```
 document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML= "<ul><li>'The total number of coins is ' + total + '.'</li><li> + quarters + ' Qaurters' +</li><li> + dimes + ' Dimes' +</li><li> + nickels + ' Nickels' +</li><li> + pennies + ' Pennies' +</li></ul>";
```